# String cleaning and formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL formatter in my application but the problem is that the customer wants to be able to enter special characters like:

> : | / - “ ‘ & * # @

I have a string:

```
string myCrazyString  = ":|/-\“‘&*#@";
```

I have a function where another string is being passed:

```
public void CleanMyString(string myStr)
{
}
```

How can I compare the string being passed "myStr" to "myCrazyString" and if "myStr has any of the characters in myCrazyString to remove it?

So if I pass to my function:

> "this ' is a" cra@zy: me|ssage/ an-d I& want#to clea*n it"

It should return:

"this is a crazy message and I want to clean it"

How can I do this in my CleanMyString function?

Comment: Why do you want to remove those characters?

Comment: It seems like a regex problem, but I am slightly confused as to why the customer wants to be able to enter these, but you then want to remove them? WHy not stop the customer entering them?

Comment: yeah some crazy customers lol

Comment: something more than just removing the crazy chars from myStr has to be done to get the output in your example :) just removing the crazy chars would result in "this  is a crazy message and I wantto clean it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Regular Expression for that Like:

```
pattern = @"(:|\||\/|\-|\\|\“|\‘|\&|\*|\#|\@)";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, string.Empty);
```

- split each string you want to remove by `|`
- To remove the special characters like the `|` itself use `\`, so `\|` this will handle the `|` as normal character.

Test:

```
inputString = @"H\I t&he|r#e!";
//output is: HI there!
```

Comment: Oh great so If I have a | it would be ||| ?

Comment: `pattern = "[|/-\“‘&*#@]";` is a better answer

Comment: @user good question, if you have `|` then use `\|` for it. so the pattern will be `pattern = @"(!|@|&|\|)"`, note that I added `@` at the string. or else you have to use it `\\|` like `pattern = "(!|@|&|\\|)"`

Comment: One last one, and if the chaacter to be removed is a \ then I would do |\| ? wouldn't it try to scape the second | and having trouble addind the " too :( lol?

Comment: @user: no it will be \\ so `pattern = @"(!|@|&|\||\\)"` in general the \ is to escape characters. so \| will escape | and \\ will escape \

Comment: Great, the only one left is the " when i add \" it is ommiting the remaining string still for some reason.. it is not scaping it..

Comment: So my final pattern looks like this Pattern = @"(/|-|'|&|#|!|@|[|]|(|)|?|\""|\||\\)";

Comment: Thank you very much I am accepting your answer, the only thing is as Panda mentioned.. where the # is it is not retaining a space.. but i guess I would figure something out... thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

solution without regular expressions, just for availability purposes:

```
    static string clear(string input)
    {
        string charsToBeCleared = ":|/-\“‘&*#@";
        string output = "";
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (charsToBeCleared.IndexOf(c) < 0)
            {
                output += c;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex as others mentioned, or code like this:

```
char[] myCrazyChars  = "\"\':|/-\\“‘&*#@".ToCharArray();
string myCrazyString = "this ' is a\" cra@zy: me|ssage/ an-d I& want#to clea*n it";
string[] splittedCrazyString = myCrazyString.Split(myCrazyChars);
string notCrazyStringAtAll = string.Join("", splittedCrazyString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a Regular Expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly straight-forward way to do it. Split the string based on all of the characters in your "crazy string and then join them back together without the bad characters.

```
string myCrazyString  = @":|/-\“‘&*#@";
string str = @"this ' is a"" cra@zy: me|ssage/ an-d I& want#to clea*n it";
string[] arr = str.Split(myCrazyString.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
str = string.Join(string.Empty, arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
namespace RemoveChars
{
    class Program
    {
        static string str = @"this ' is a\“ cra@zy: me|ssage/ an-d I& want#to clea*n it";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CleanMyString(str);
        }

        public static void CleanMyString(string myStr)
        {
            string myCrazyString  = @":|/-\“‘&*#@";
            var result = "";
            foreach (char c in myStr)
            {
                var t = true; // t will remain true if c is not a crazy char
                foreach (char ch in myCrazyString)
                    if (c == ch)
                    {
                        t = false;
                        break;
                    }
                if (t)
                    result += c;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Panda, you are really taking care of the "#" case.

Answer (score -1):

You could try an if statement and if a character is present then mention the craziness

```
 if (myCrazyString.Contains("@"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This string is out of controL!");
        }
```

Regex is also a good idea(Maybe better)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

1.Define a StringBuilder

2.Iterate through the characters of the string to be cleaned.

3.Put everything required in the StringBuilder and ignore other special charactersby simply putting if conditions.

4.Rerurn StringBuilder.

Or

Try using Regular Expression.